# Converting list of tuples with varying number of elements into columns in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is my first post. I am coding a combinatorial algorithm for an engineering project at University. I am using Python and Pandas..

I have a Pandas dataframe with several columns, one of which is a list of over 20k tuples.
The number of elements per tuple vary from `1` to `6.`
i.e:

```
(10),
(10,20),
(20,30,40),
(20,30,40,50),
(10,20,30,40,50),
(10,20,30,40,50,60)
```

I want to convert this into `6` columns. The blank columns, with no entries should be zeroed.

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to expand your tuples.  Given several lists, you can add them together.  For example, ['apple'] + ['pear'] = ['apple', 'pear'].  And ['apple'] * 2 = ['apple', 'apple'].

The same principle applies to tuples, so (10, 20) + (0,) * 4 = (10, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0). The tuples are thus expanded with zeros.

There is a check to see if the value is a tuple in the first place (see the first row).  If not, use that value and expand it as a tuple.

```
s = pd.Series([(10), 
               (10,20), 
               (20,30,40), 
               (20,30,40,50), 
               (10,20,30,40,50), 
               (10,20,30,40,50,60)])

>>> s
0                          10
1                    (10, 20)
2                (20, 30, 40)
3            (20, 30, 40, 50)
4        (10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
5    (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)
dtype: object

>>> pd.DataFrame([t + (0,) * (6 - len(t)) if isinstance(t, tuple) 
                  else (t,) + (0,) * 5 
                  for t in s])
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0  10   0   0   0   0   0
1  10  20   0   0   0   0
2  20  30  40   0   0   0
3  20  30  40  50   0   0
4  10  20  30  40  50   0
5  10  20  30  40  50  60
```